# Messed up On Screen Keyboard

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, accessibility

My OnScreen keyboard seems to be a little messed up—only a few buttons show despite my physical keyboard having the full character set (for USA Devorak).

This is what I've tried so far:
1. Windows update
2. Switching keyboard language
but neither worked.

How do I get my on screen keyboard showing the full keyboard layout?  Any assistance would be appreciated.

[image: On Screen Keyboard]

Answer (score 0):

Press the <kbd>General</kbd> key... its in navigation mode right now. Pressing it will go back into normal mode.